Merklich, erkennbar, bemerkbar, auffällig?
Könnt ihr für mich einen Beispielsatz für jedes Wort schreiben?
Ich habe gar keine Ahnung darüber, wie die unterschiedlich sind.

GSE honoriert "eigenen Einsatz" bezüglich der Frage, und der Online-Duden (Duden.de) listet Synonyme, so dass du die schonmal selbst herausfinden kannst. "Schreib mir einen Beispielsatz" ist keine erwünschte Frage.

All these adjektices are derived from verbs, so you might want to look at these.

https://www.dwds.de/ lists examples for each. As such ... can this be answered by a dictionary or thesaurus?

Seine Kraft ließ merklich nach.
Der Unterschied zwischen Wasser und Schnaps ist optisch nicht erkennbar.
Bei dem dichten Nebel war seine Anwesenheit kaum bemerkbar.
Er hat eine sehr auffällige Haarfarbe.
